# Why do I have to reboot my router occasionally to stop gradual network degradation?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking

I have a Netgear C7000v2 AC1900 modem/wifi router and I've found over the last year that I have to restart it almost daily or else over time when I play Overwatch I start seeing more and more packet loss and latency. Right after I restart it I usually hover around 40ms average latency communicating with the Chicago server with little/no loss. After about 12+ hours I start seeing latency spikes to 100ms with the occasional packet loss. By 24 hours later it's spikes to 200ms latency with more than just a little loss. I'm not really sure what restarting the router does. Is it a hardware issue? Some sort of software issue?

Comment: It may need a firmware update and/or different settings for gaming.

Comment: There's no way to determine the exact issue without reviewing the system log, and even then, it may not be conclusive without the ability to SSH into the router or without flashing a debug firmware image from Netgear _(tech support would provide such an image)_. It's unlikely the issue is a result of the traffic in and of itself and this is something you'd want to reach out to Netgear to troubleshoot since it's unlikely the C7000v2 offers the ability to SSH into it and would likely need a debug firmware image that outputs a continuous kernel and system log to a specific local port.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In my experience, this is how consumer-grade routers act when they are dying.

Comment: The most likely cause is a lack of QoS if you don't have it configured - assign static IPs to the devices you're using to game and configure QoS to give their IPs, MACs, or port numbers priority over all other traffic.

Answer (score 1):

First, the thing that works (half the time) is to do a firmware update, do a hard reset of the router to factory specifications, set it up again and test it.

If the above fails to resolve the issue, that would be the time to replace with a new router.

Answer (score 1):

In very broad terms, domestic routers have a brain the size of a peanut & are easily confused.

They open ports, then lose track, so the port gets clogged, things go stale & the internal tables quickly fill the RAM. The poor little thing just doesn't cope well.
Some games are worse than others for spewing a myriad constantly-changing connections; this just exacerbates the situation.

One online game I used to work helpline on would open up to 400 connections at once*, all short-lived, ephemeral. On many of the lower end domestic routers this would entail a reboot every day or so to keep them up to speed.
I fixed my own issues by installing a corporate gateway… now I reboot for firmware updates every month or four, with zero issues in between.

<sup>I checked this using the much more advanced gateway with comprehensive inbuilt stats & logs. Sometimes with two of us playing in the same house, it would read over 2,000 simultaneous connections. This was no problem at all for the big-brained device, but would cause issues on a domestic router</sup>

Comment: This answer doesn't make logical sense, as the vast majority of modern routers have more than adequate specs _(C7000v2 has a 1.6GHz CPU, 256MB RAM, and 128MB of flash)_, using the same programs one would on a Linux distro, the bulk of which generally comes from BusyBox, and are more than capable of handling thousands of simultaneous connections without stressing the CPU. This answer speaks in general terms not specifically applied to the OP's router and context matters in this case.

Comment: I don't know that router at all - but I worked long enough on the helpline to know that the symptom is typical & the fix is to just restart it. I never said it would make the CPU too busy, I said the RAM would fill & the routing tables would get clogged.

Comment: It's simply not possible for the RAM to become filled from routing packets, as it's not RAM intensive, especially not on devices with 128MB+ of RAM. This answer's generalized info seems to be applicable to devices with <64MB of RAM _(routers route >1M packets/sec with very little RAM)_, as it's not packet routing that takes up RAM on most routers, it's software having nothing to do w/ routing _(e.g. file shares, VPNs, etc.)_. This can be easily seen on a router's WebUI's metrics page, router's system log, `htop`, etc. A lack of QoS would be the simplest answer for what's going on.

Comment: How would poorly set QoS be 'reset' by rebooting the device & how would the issue be fixed entirely by using one with 4GB RAM instead of <128MB? …and why don't you put all these comments into an actual answer?

Comment: A lack of QoS, not poorly set QoS. The only routers requiring >256MB RAM are those running full distros, versus embedded, or routers using Samba _(due to HW buffer, as large transfers can fill RAM & cause a crash)_ - for example, I use both Sophos UTM  [built upon OpenSUSE] w/ 8GB RAM on custom hardware & OpenWrt on a Linksys WRT1900ACS & WRT32X w/ 512MB RAM & routing packets simply doesn't fill up RAM _(perhaps on a corporate network, but not a consumer LAN & certainly not from gaming)_. I haven't created an answer as there's vital info lacking from the OPs question required to formulate one

Comment: It's easy to determine if RAM is the issue - OP looks at the WebUI's metrics page, noting RAM usage and active connections before gaming, during gaming, 12 hrs later, then again 24hrs later.

Comment: It's much harder to determine at consumer level if the routing tables & open ports are confuzzled. Ports open & fail to close, leaving them stuck, meaning the system has to offer alternatives, which may or may not be re-routed correctly. tbh, I don't really know how this all works on a technical level, but I do know that it does happen. When I was helping on support, this was handed down in general terms from the guys who actually ran the server network for the game. Keeping it simple so we could pass it on to users.